# How to run css transform animations without any hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I want to make a svg grow in side over a second. I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <script src="js/plugin/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            /* Shorthand version */
            .hub-icon-container svg {
                position: relative;
                /* Firefox */
                -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
                /* WebKit */
                -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
                /* Opera */
                -o-transition: all 1s ease;
                /* Standard */
                transition: all 1s ease;
            }

            .hub-icon-container svg:hover {
                width: 500px;  
                height: 500px;  
            }


        </style>


    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hub-icon-container">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="70px" height="70px" viewBox="0 0 70 70" enable-background="new 0 0 70 70" xml:space="preserve">
                <g class="hub-icon">
                    <path fill="#9B59B6" d="M64.142 23.032L35.001 34.998l14.533 6.271 18.908-7.766c0.689-0.285 1.026-1.087 0.744-1.782l-3.265-7.946C65.635 23.079 64.835 22.747 64.142 23.032z"/>
                    <path fill="#F74ED7" d="M64.068 47.142L35.001 34.998l5.845 14.712 18.861 7.876c0.688 0.29 1.495-0.04 1.783-0.73l3.312-7.931C65.09 48.233 64.763 47.431 64.068 47.142z"/>
                    <path fill="#F2C40D" d="M46.97 64.138l-11.97-29.14 -6.268 14.534L36.5 68.44c0.284 0.689 1.084 1.026 1.779 0.743l7.946-3.265C46.919 65.634 47.256 64.833 46.97 64.138z"/>
                    <path fill="#E67E22" d="M22.863 64.069l12.138-29.071 -14.707 5.846 -7.877 18.859c-0.292 0.692 0.039 1.497 0.731 1.784l7.93 3.311C21.771 65.089 22.573 64.76 22.863 64.069z"/>
                    <path fill="#E74C3C" d="M5.865 46.966l29.136-11.968 -14.531-6.267L1.562 36.498c-0.693 0.285-1.028 1.089-0.741 1.78l3.263 7.947C4.369 46.919 5.168 47.254 5.865 46.966z"/>
                    <path fill="#19BC9C" d="M5.935 22.858l29.065 12.14 -5.839-14.707 -18.863-7.876c-0.693-0.29-1.495 0.039-1.785 0.73l-3.311 7.931C4.914 21.768 5.241 22.57 5.935 22.858z"/>
                    <path fill="#2ECC71" d="M23.032 5.862l11.969 29.136 6.269-14.528L33.506 1.563c-0.286-0.697-1.089-1.03-1.783-0.746l-7.944 3.268C23.084 4.366 22.75 5.168 23.032 5.862z"/>
                    <path fill="#3398DB" d="M47.142 5.934L35.001 34.998l14.707-5.841L57.589 10.3c0.286-0.697-0.044-1.499-0.735-1.789l-7.929-3.308C48.232 4.911 47.432 5.245 47.142 5.934z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </body>

</html>
```

But this works if I hover it. How can I get it to start growing (over 1 second) as soon as the page loads or I dynamically attach the class to it. If I remove the `:hover`, then it just starts off fully grows and does not animate. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use a keyframe as the following

```
/* Shorthand version */
.hub-icon-container svg {
position: relative;
/* Firefox */
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
/* WebKit */
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
/* Opera */
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
/* Standard */
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.hub-icon-container svg:hover {
width: 500px;  
height: 500px;  
}

.hub-icon-container svg {
-webkit-animation: blowup 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
-moz-animation:    blowup 5s infinite;/* Fx 5+ */
-o-animation:      blowup 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
animation:         blowup 5s infinite;/* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dshun/985bzyu8/